# Rayleigh-Ritz quotient

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

My question is very simple:

Let $A$ be the (symmetric) adjacency matrix of a graph with $n$ vertices, let $\lambda_1$ be the largest eigenvalue of $A$ and let $v$ be a vector with $n$ real coordinates, written as a column.

Prove that if $R(A,v) = \lambda_1$, then $v$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_1$, that is, if
$\frac{v^{t}Av}{||v||^{2}} = \lambda_1$, then $Av = \lambda_1v$.

I would appreciate any short but clear answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=BDB^{T}$ with $D$ diagonal, and with diagonal entries $D_{i,i} = \lambda_i$ and $B$ orthonormal.

We then have
$$
x^T A x = (x^T B)D(B^{T}x)= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_iy_i^2
$$
where $y_i$ are the entries of $B^{T}x$.

On the other hand we have $x^T x=(x^T B)(B^{T}x) = \sum \limits_{i=1}^n y_i^2$ (because $B$ is orthonormal).

It follows that in order for $R(A,v)$ to be $\lambda_1$ all the $y_i$ such that $\lambda_i \neq \lambda_1$ must be $0$. One can then evaluate
$$
Ax = BDB^{T}x = B(D(B^{T}x)) = B(\lambda B^{T} x) = \lambda x.
$$
Notice this works for any real symmetric matrix.